# Add default_value to a name field in a .yml file

Tags: 8, migrations

I am using the migrate source CSV module. I have a few records that do not have the *Contact* field set or its value is null; the migration fails for this reason. I tried using the default_value plugin that ships with core, but I keep getting the following error.

> A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 42 (near `default_value: 'Full Name'`).

```yaml
process:
  uid: EIN
  field_contractor_name: CONTACT
  name: CONTACT
  -  
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: 'Full Name'
```

How do I get a default value added to that field when a value is not present in the record?

Answer (score 0):

The correct YAML to use is the following one.

```yaml
process:
  uid: EIN
  field_contractor_name:
    - 
      plugin: get
      source: CONTACT
    -
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: 'Full Name'
```